# Anaconda and pkg-config on osx 10.10: how to prevent pip installation problems?

Tags: python, igraph, anaconda, pkg-config

I'm using anaconda python 2.7, and keep finding problems installing python libraries using pip that seem to rely on `pkg-config`. In particular, `python-igraph` (although the author of that library kindly added a patch to help conda users) and `louvain` (which I have yet to fix).

Would installing pkg-config lead to conflicts with anaconda? Is there a way to set them up to play nice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced some installation issues with Anaconda and my fix was to download manually the components of the Anaconda package.

If you use `sudo apt-get python3-numpy`
for example, it will download as well as all the dependencies.

So all you have to do is download the major libraries.

Although I don't believe pkg-config causes conflicts with Anaconda. Give it a shot, should be easy to resolve issues if any at all.